# Message missing in e-mail depending on order of bodypart adds

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, attachment, html-email

**The problem I'm experiencing** is when I add the message Body part of the e-mail to the message object before I add the attachments the body of the e-mail doesn't show up, but when I add the message body part after all the attachments it shows up fine.

This is weird, but I have an e-mail I'm trying to send using JavaMail. It has all the regular stuff you need for an e-mail (addresses, etc). The "email" object you'll see below is a Javabean that holds mimeBodyParts for attachments as well as a mimeBodyPart for the message body, subject, etc...

Here's the code that does **not** work (as described above)

```
Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("alternative");
message.setSubject(email.getSubject());
multipart.addBodyPart(email.getContentBodyPart()); //This is the only line that moves
for (MimeBodyPart mimeBodyPart : email.getBodyParts()) {
  multipart.addBodyPart(mimeBodyPart);
}
message.setContent(multipart);
```

Here's the code that **does** work:

```
Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("alternative");
message.setSubject(email.getSubject());
for (MimeBodyPart mimeBodyPart : email.getBodyParts()) {
  multipart.addBodyPart(mimeBodyPart);
}
multipart.addBodyPart(email.getContentBodyPart()); //This is the only line that moved
message.setContent(multipart);
```

If you need more info about the email javabean I'll give it to you (or you can find the entire object code [here](https://github.com/kentcdodds/Java-Helper/blob/master/src/com/kentcdodds/javahelper/model/Email.java)), but I'm guessing I'm just missing something simple. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're creating a message with attachments, why are you using a multipart/alternative?  You should be using the (default) multipart/mixed.

Did you cut and paste that code without understanding it?  :-)

Comment: Ok ok, I _did_ cut and paste the "alternative" part, but everything else I understood :) Haha. I looked it up and figured out what that constructor is all about now I get it and it works great :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify for anyone else reading this: If you use an "alternative" MimeMultipart, all its parts should be alternative versions of the same content. Also according to the relevant RFCs the preferred version of the content should be added last. You do this a lot when creating an HTML email with a plain text fallback. This is why they warn you in the JavaMail docs to read the RFCs.